# SGD diverging after changing learning rate

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am creating a function for stochastic gradient descent with ridge regression. I am keeping the step size constant for 1800 iterations and then changing it to 1/n or 1/sqrt(n). When I use 1/sqrt(n) my loss is decreasing and almost converging. However when I use 1/n my loss decreases and then starts to increase! Can someone please help me. The code for SGC is below and also the function which I use to compute the loss for the entire batch after every update.

```
def stochastic_grad_descent_steptrial(x,y,thetha,alpha,num_iter,lambda_reg):

    loss_log=[]
    theta_log=[]
    ridge_log=[]

    total_loss_log=[]  # total loss for updates(for plotting)
    total_iter_count=[]
    for j in range(num_iter): # j epochs
        for i in range(x.shape[0]): 


            diff=np.dot(x.iloc[i,:],thetha)-y[i]  # loss of each i
            loss=np.sum(diff**2)+lambda_reg*np.sum(thetha**2)
            loss_log.append(loss) # append to log

            diff=np.dot(x.iloc[i,:],thetha)-y[i] # specific i
            grad=(2/N)*np.dot(x.iloc[i,:].T,diff)+2*lambda_reg*thetha # grad for i


            total_iter=((j+1)*(i+1)) # Total step number till now 
            total_iter_count.append(total_iter)


            if total_iter<1800:        # change to step size function only after n steps 
                step=alpha             # Can use function and step condition as hyper parameter
            else:
                step=1/(total_iter)
#                 step=1/np.sqrt(total_iter)

            thetha=thetha-step*grad #update


            #appends
            theta_log.append(thetha) 
            ridge_log.append(lambda_reg*np.sum(thetha**2))  


            # compute loss on entire data 
            total_loss=ridge_loss(x,y,thetha,lambda_reg) 
            total_loss_log.append(total_loss) # append

    normal_loss=cost(x,y,thetha) #final loss(without ridge)

    loss_log=np.array(loss_log)  # conversions to np,pd
    theta_log=pd.DataFrame(theta_log)
    ridge_log=np.array(ridge_log)

    return(loss_log,theta_log,ridge_log,thetha,normal_loss,total_loss_log)
```

My loss function(which is then plotted) is:

```
def ridge_loss(x,y,thetha,lambda_reg):

    diff=np.dot(x,thetha)-y
    cost=(1/N)*np.sum(diff**2)+lambda_reg*np.sum(thetha**2)
    return(cost)
```

Why is the loss increasing? (See graphs below) How can the loss increase, shouldn't it just slowly decrease anyways?

[Link to dataset](https://github.com/neha-duggirala/100DaysOfMLCode/blob/master/linear_regression/1.txt)

Image 1 is with constant rate, image 2 is with square root iteration 
number and image 3 is 1 over iteration number.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your loss graphs are not included. I edited the question so that it does not refer to them, but please edit it yourself and add them if possible.

Comment: I am trying to put the graphs but it is reconizing them as code and giving indentation error

Comment: I have added images, but the text was recongnized as code for some reason

Comment: Fixed it for you!

Comment: Thank! Also solve the problem if you can!

Comment: It looks like your step size is much larger when you are basing it off of the total number of iterations instead of the square root. I'd first suggest setting `lambda_reg=1` and seeing if you converge, then maybe do some hyperparameter tuning on `lambda_reg`.

Comment: In general, when you switch from your beginning case (first 10 iterations) to one of your adaptive step sizes, your step size jumps up a lot! You might try making sure the step size is always decreasing too.

Comment: Resolved! Thanks. Incorrect iterations counter